# How to intercept events when navigator changes in a Weex app?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, weex

I use `vue-router` in my weex app, and manage jumping in pages by `this.$router.push` and `this.$router.go(-1)`.
However, my weex app is a SPA, and when clicking the RETURN entity key in Android, the whole page is closed. How can I intercept events when clicking the RETURN entity key in Android and stop it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use weex navigator to get support for the native RETURN
https://weex.incubator.apache.org/references/modules/navigator.html